# Firebase init functions doesn't create /functions/ files

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I've been working with Firebase for a while.
Now, when I'm trying to init the Functions for a new Firebase project, it seems to create it, but the Functions folder is empty. When I try to redo it, it claims that the files are there.

Does it have to do with the new codebase feature?

The output of the `firebase init functions`

```
i  Using project example (Example)

=== Functions Setup

Detected existing codebase(s): default, another

? Would you like to initialize a new codebase, or overwrite an existing one? Overwrite
? Which codebase would you like to overwrite? default

Overwriting codebase default...

? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript
? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? No
? File functions/package.json already exists. Overwrite? Yes
+  Wrote functions/package.json
? File functions/index.js already exists. Overwrite? Yes
+  Wrote functions/index.js
? File functions/.gitignore already exists. Overwrite? Yes
+  Wrote functions/.gitignore
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes

up to date, audited 515 packages in 645ms

47 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Also please edit the question to show the entire output of the CLI from the moment you ran the command.

Comment: Could you show the **complete** output from the moment you run the command?  What you have right now is not complete.  There should be an ascii "FIREBASE" header. There could be important information missing here.  Also please reply in comments using @ to notify me if you've made a change.

Comment: Also you should note the path where you are running the command, and any other shell commands you use to observe the results.

Comment: @DougStevenson, i have the same issue on M1. Following tutorial from Firebase docs, the folder is empty after running firebase init.